# Saving the "state" of a Z3 solver in SMT2 format

Tags: python, z3, z3py

is it possible, using the Z3 API (e.g. the Python API), to save the current state of a solver, **including what the solver has learned** (in SAT solving we would say the "learned clauses") in a file in SMT2 format?

Because I would like to be able to save the state of the solver in a temporary file in order to resume solving later, in order to have some time to understand what further queries I should make to it.

Many thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SMT2 has no provisions of saving a given solvers state, which will no doubt differ widely from solver to solver. Each solver might have different mechanisms of doing so, however, but it will definitely not be in SMTLib2 format.

Since your question is entirely Z3 specific, I recommend asking it on https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/issues to see if they might have anything interesting. So far as I know, however, this isn't possible currently.

Comment: Many thanks for this Levent! What I am thinking is that the so-called learned clauses should just be some additional assertions added by the solver, like the learned clauses in SAT solving, am I wrong? If not, is there a way to print them somehow? Even not in SMT2 format (I would have preferred the SMT2 format just to be more comfortable)

Comment: Even if this is possible, it would no doubt refer to many internal variables/data-structures that wouldn't make sense outside the solver's execution context. Definitely not in any text/ascii format at least. Still, asking at the z3 github page is your best bet to see if they have any recommendations.

Comment: @LeventErkok I don't see your point, clauses are just clauses.. what data structures should be there?

Comment: @PatrickTrentin I doubt the solver would represent it's learned lemmas as clauses that can be dumped readily in an SMTLib or ASCII readable format. It'll be in the solvers internal data-types, which will be almost impossible to render for external use as the OP requested.

Comment: @LeventErkok I don't understand what you imagine this internal datatype to be, in other solvers I've experience of its just a number of indexes, vectors and maps, which however have a very straightforward mapping to clauses.. and in these solvers the same representation is used for external and internally generated ones.

Comment: @PatrickTrentin I'd be happily surprised to find out if Z3 had such a facility. As I originally suggested, it's best to follow up with them to see if what OP is asking for is possible.

Comment: @PatrickTrentin Here's the response from Z3 developers: https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/issues/1044

As suspected, they do not provide a means of "serializing" the internal state containing the lemmas. I suspect you'll find this is true for almost all solvers out there.

Comment: @LeventErkok i was not disputing that fact, though it surely is good to have info from developers

Answer (score 0):

At the end Levent was right :)

Below are some observations by Nikolaj Bjorner, from the Z3 github website.

"**The state of the solver isn't fully serializable to SMT2 format.**
You can print the solver to smt2 format based on the current assertions,
**but not learned clauses/units** using the **sexpr()** method on the Solver object."

...

"We don't expose ways to print internal state. You could perhaps **interrupt** the solver, then **clone** it using the "translate" methods and access the translated solver state using internal print utilities. You would have to change the code a bit to get to this state.
The print features on solvers don't access the internal state of any of the solvers, instead they look at the asserted formulas and print them.
**I don't translate learned lemmas**. For example, the code in smt_context.cpp line 176 is disabled because it didn't help with any performance enhancements. Similarly, the copy code in sat_solver does not copy learned clauses even though it retains unit literals and binary clauses that are learned."

You can see the above comments by Nicolaj at this [link](https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/issues/1044#issuecomment-304481565).