# Z3 Optimize timeout

Tags: c#, .net, z3

I want to set a timeout in z3 so i dont get a optimal solution but one that fits the constraints.
I use .Net and tried something like this:

```
using(Context context = new Context(new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "model", "true" } })) {
    var solver = context.MkSolver(); // i actually want to use MkOptimize() 
    Params p = context.MkParams();
    p.Add("timeout", 1000);
    solver.Parameters = p;
    IntExpr x = context.MkIntConst("x");
    // ...
    solver.Check();
    solver.Model.Evaluate(x);
}
```

The timeout is working correct but i cant use the so far found solution because solver.Check() is UNKNOWN ...

When i use MkOptimize instead of MkSolver i get a unknown parameter exception

So my question now is how do i get the best solution so far after the timeout and how can i use this with MkOptimize

Answer (score 1):

I'd very much doubt that you can reliably get a "best-so-far" answer when the solver says `Unknown` due to timeout or any other reason. Even if you got a model, it wouldn't necessarily satisfy all your constraints at that point. Since this is a very Z3 specific question, you might get better mileage asking at https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/issues and summarizing the answer you get back over here for the community.

Comment: **z3** surely keeps the latest known optimal approximation saved somewhere because it is used by the optimisation algorithm: this value is a reliable *best-so-far* answer for a *timeout* event. So it just needs to be printed out. **OptiMathSAT** does that, and also saves the entire formula model along the optimisation search, so that it is always possible to dump the model corresponding to the *best-so-far* optimum value even when a *timeout* occurs, provided that such *approximate solution* was found.

Comment: Fair point. But what's available in some internal data structures and what's available to the user via an API  after a timeout may not be the same. There was a similar discussion regarding solver state a while ago:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44110746/saving-the-state-of-a-z3-solver-in-smt2-format. That's why I encouraged the OP to ask directly to Z3 developers at their github site, where I know they are quite responsive.